# how to you keep a formula to stay with a certain cell even when you insert a cell to the right

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a date in cell D3 AND THEN IN CELL C2 I HAVE THIS FORMULA:

```
=DATE(YEAR(D3)+1,MONTH(D3),DAY(D3)-1)
```

Which adds the date for review a year on. but when I need to insert the cell to the right to add a new date it changes the formula to cell E3 and i want it to stay in D3 and calculate from the new date. i have tried indirect function but i cant get it to work with the date format

Please help

Comment: You could try using `indirect`

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT`:

- `=DATE(YEAR(INDIRECT("D3",TRUE))+1,MONTH(INDIRECT("D3",TRUE)),DAY(INDIRECT("D3",TRUE))-1)`
- `=DATE(YEAR(OFFSET(C2,1,1))+1,MONTH(OFFSET(C2,1,1)),DAY(OFFSET(C2,1,1))-1)`

Comment: Thank you I will try this when I'm back in work tomorrow. I really appriciate you taking the time to answer my problem.

Comment: +1 for the `OFFSET()` option, which will still maintain functionality if the sheet is modified in a row above or column to the left of `C2`